# Getting Failed status when Twilio adds +1 in prefix to 501 area code

Tags: twilio

1). Using Twilio, when I fill in the phone number and choose the Belize 501 area code and submit a form, it automatically shows the 10-digit number on Twilio.

2). But Belize Country code(+501) is also considered with the phone number in Twilio account. and by default Twilio added the US country code (+1) in Prefix before the phone number. How can solve this? How can I remove the US country code and the supported Belize country code with 7 digit phone number?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you are placing calls to Belize, ensure that you include the `+` at the start of the number too. For legacy reasons, Twilio considers phone numbers that are not in [e.164 format](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-e164) to be US local numbers. So, when you are dialling the Belize number in your example, make sure to use the full international form: `+5018861219`.